# Working with Lists - 'variable does not exist' error

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm new in Apex and I'm trying build a Hierarchy Tree with 4 objects: Account, Carteira__c, Produtos_das_carteiras__r and AtivosFundo__c

One Account can have N Carteira__c

One Carteira__c can have N Produtos_das_carteiras__r

One Produtos_das_carteiras__r can have N AtivosFundo__c

I wrote the code below as my Controller, but the following error is appearing: **'Variable does not exist: tempativos'**

Can someone help me, please?

```
Public with sharing class TreeDetalhes {
Private final Account acct;
Public TreeDetalhes(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
    }

Class cNodes {
Public Account gparent {get;set;}
Public List<Carteira__c> parent {get; set;}
Public List<AtivosFundo__c> gchildren {get; set;}

Public cNodes(Account gp, List<Carteira__c> p, List<AtivosFundo__c> gc)
{
 gparent = gp;
 parent = p;
 gchildren = gc;
}
}

Public List<cNodes> hierarchy;

Public List<cNodes> getmainnodes()
{
    hierarchy = new List<cNodes>();
    List<Account> tempparent = [Select Id,Name from Account where id = :acct.Id];
    for (Integer i =0; i< tempparent.size() ; i++)
    {
        List<Carteira__c> tempchildren = [Select Id,Name,(Select Id,Aloc__c, Fundos__r.Name, Fundos__c from Produtos_das_carteiras__r r) from Carteira__c where Integrante__c = :tempparent[i].Id];
        for (Carteira__c c : tempchildren) {
            for (AtivosCarteira__c ac : c.Produtos_das_carteiras__r) {
                List<AtivosFundo__c> tempativos = [Select Id, FundoRelacionado__r.Name From AtivosFundo__c where Fundos__c = :ac.Fundos__c];
            }
        }
    hierarchy.add(new cNodes(tempparent[i],tempchildren,tempativos));
    }   
    return hierarchy;
}   
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring `tempativos` within the scope of the for loop.

You'll need to declare it at the same location as the `tempchildren` variable.

e.g.

```
List<Carteira__c> tempchildren = [Select Id,Name,(Select Id,Aloc__c, Fundos__r.Name, Fundos__c from Produtos_das_carteiras__r r) from Carteira__c where Integrante__c = :tempparent[i].Id];
List<AtivosFundo__c> tempativos;
    for (Carteira__c c : tempchildren) {
        for (AtivosCarteira__c ac : c.Produtos_das_carteiras__r) {
            tempativos = [Select Id, FundoRelacionado__r.Name From AtivosFundo__c where Fundos__c = :ac.Fundos__c];
        }
    }
hierarchy.add(new cNodes(tempparent[i],tempchildren,tempativos));
```

Keep in mind that you're performing a SOQL query within a for loop, which is a really bad practice.  You should look into how to bulkify your code.